# Construi uma barra de menu lateral e não consigo utilizar o espaço livre, como que coloco o texto ao lado da barra ao em vez de em baixo?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, front-end

Flex fit


    
        
            gym

- Home
- Sobre Nós
- Treino
- Flexonal
- Contate

## FLEX FIT

a academia do seu comportamento web

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    background-color:#592B02 ;
}
img{
    width: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
li{
    width: 50px;
    padding: 12px;
}
.menu{
    padding:5px;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column ;
    align-items: center;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 450px;;
}
h1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexfit.css">
    <title>Flex fit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <menu>
        <div class="menu">
            <h2 id="logo-start">gym</h2>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#home"><img src="home.png" alt="home logo">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Sobre"><img src="sobre-nós.png" alt="Sobre nós logo">Sobre Nós</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Treino"><img src="treino.png" alt="treino logo">Treino</a></li>
            <li><a href="#flexonal"><img src="flexonal.png" alt="flexonal logo">Flexonal</a></li> <!--uma piada tosca com flex + personal-->
            <li><a href="#contate-nos"><img src="contato.png" alt="contate-nos logo">Contate</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </menu>
    <h1>FLEX FIT</h1>
        <p>a academia do seu comportamento web</p>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem esta opção também onde coloca todo o conteúdo

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #592B02;
}

img {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

li {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.menu {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 450px;
  ;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexfit.css">
  <title>Flex fit</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <menu class="menu">
      <div>
        <h2 id="logo-start">gym</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#home"><img src="home.png" alt="home logo">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Sobre"><img src="sobre-nós.png" alt="Sobre nós logo">Sobre Nós</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Treino"><img src="treino.png" alt="treino logo">Treino</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#flexonal"><img src="flexonal.png" alt="flexonal logo">Flexonal</a>
          </li>
          <!--uma piada tosca com flex + personal-->
          <li>
            <a href="#contate-nos"><img src="contato.png" alt="contate-nos logo">Contate</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </menu>
    <h1>FLEX FIT</h1>
    <p>a academia do seu comportamento web</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

me um div main e no CSS coloca como display:flex, assim os elementos ficarão lado a lado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa fazer duas coisas no seu codigo pra ele funcionar.
Primeiro, o seu texto está voando na página, ele é um elemento individual, então precisa estar delimitado por alguma coisa.
A estrutura mais correta aí seria :

```html
<body>
  <menu>
    aqui o código do menu
    ..
    ..
    ..
   </menu>
   
   <main>
      <div>
        <h1>FLEX FIT</h1>
        <p>a academia do seu comportamento web</p>
      </div>
   </main>
```

Porque neste caso eu coloquei o MAIN? pq ele vai separar os demais conteúdos de bloco do teu conteúdo MENU
Além disso, dentro do MAIN você vai poder jogar outros códigos (header, tabelas, listas, etc) sem quebrar para baixo.

Depois de fazer isso no main, vá até o seu CSS e acrescente esta única linha no BODY{}

```css
body{
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

O flex-inline vai dizer para a página que todos os elementos de bloco dentro do body ficarão lado a lado, e não embaixo.

Assim, você vai ter
body[
menu | main
]
e não
body [
menu
main
]

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]